# How to export a named docker volume on a Mac?

Tags: docker

I have a docker named volume called "app_data". I simply want to export this volume so that I can move it to a different host machine.

After some reading, I understand there're 2 ways of doing this.

1. Retrieve the volume file from host file system as discovered by the command `docker volume inspect app_data`
2. Create a TAR ball export from docker volume using a command close to
   `docker run --rm --volumes-from database -v $(pwd):/backup debian:jessie tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /app_data`

However, I cannot get either one of these options to work for me.

1. Option 1 is not working for me as I am running this on a Mac and what `docker volume inspect app_data` gives me is the path of the VM file system. Is there a way to access this file from VM to my Mac?
2. Option 2 is not working as it fails saying `tar: Removing leading '/' from member names
   tar: /app_data: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`
   Am i using this command correctly?

I am looking for the minimal set of commands to get this job done.
Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: In the second case you don't seem to mount the `app_data` volume, don't you need to add `-v app_data:/app_data` to (and possibly remove `--volumes-from database` from) the command line? What `tar` says is that `/app_data` does not exist inside your container.

Comment: @erikced, yes you are right i rearranged my command as `docker run --rm -v app_data:/app_data -v $(pwd):/backup debian:jessie tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /app_data` and then it created the tar file under my working directory. i.e. user directory. Thanks!

Comment: i am curious to know if i can achieve this with option 1 above. Is there a way to access VM file system at all?

Comment: I think there is a bug with Docker named volumes on Mac: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1856

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like  your second option should work. Perhaps trying mounting the volume explicitly `docker run -v app_data:/app_data`

If you're still having problems, you can actually mount the Docker VM storage, which is a qcow file, using https://github.com/libyal/libqcow/wiki/Mounting